# MySQL: set update_date to create_date if not setted

Tags: mysql, sql

I have DB table , like:

```
id           create_date            update_date
1       2014-09-03 00:00:00      0000-00-00 00:00:00
2       2014-09-01 00:00:00      0000-00-00 00:00:00
3       2014-09-01 00:00:00      2014-09-02 00:00:00
4       2014-09-02 00:00:00      0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

how to set "update_date" to be as "create_date" if it 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ?

to be:

```
id           create_date            update_date
1       2014-09-03 00:00:00      2014-09-03 00:00:00 
2       2014-09-01 00:00:00      2014-09-01 00:00:00 
3       2014-09-01 00:00:00      2014-09-02 00:00:00   <- not changed
4       2014-09-02 00:00:00      2014-09-02 00:00:00
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query

```
UPDATE table 
SET update_date=create_date 
where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(update_date) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update TABLE set update_date=create_date where update_date='0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Comment: While this may be an answer to the question, a few words of explanation would be useful to future readers.